# 1984 IMO Q4 Geometry proof check

Tags: solution-verification, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

Let ABCD be a convex quadrilateral for which the circle of diameter AB is tangent to the line CD. Show that the circle of diameter CD is tangent to the line AB if and only if the lines BC and AD are parallel.

My solution:

If the $AD = BC$ the result is obvious. Suppose WLOG $BC < AD$ and extend $CD$ to meet $AB$ at $P$.

Let $CP=h$, $BP=m$, $CD/2=r$, and $AB/2=R$.

Let the centre of the circle with diameter $AB$ be $S$ and the foot of the perpendicular from $S$ to $CD$ be $T$.

Let the centre of the circle with diameter $CD$ be $Q$ and the foot of the perpendicular from $Q$ to $AB$ be $N$. Let $QN=x$.

The lines $BC$ and $AD$ are parallel iff PBC and PAD are similar, which is the case iff

$\frac{h}{m}=\frac{h+2r}{m+2R}\iff\frac{h}{m}=\frac{r}{R}$

Now PQN and PST are similar:

$\therefore \frac{h+r}{x}=\frac{m+R}{R}\iff x=R\frac{h+r}{m+R}$

from which it follows that $x=r$ iff PBC and PAD are similar.

QED

I'm wondering if this solution would get full credit, and welcome any suggestions for improvement. Thanks.

Comment: Full credit may not be obtained if there is no  accompanying diagram.   Further, if Q N is perpendicular to AB at N, QN is automatically the radius of the circle CND and therefore x = r automatically.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. Agree about the diagram but not sure about your other assertion? I agree that N belongs to some circle CND, but this isn’t necessarily the circle with diameter CD. The implicit assumption is that the circle with diameter CD might not pass through N initially, and so that’s why QN is defined as a variable x.

Comment: If  required to prove a statement of "... if and only if....." , then for full credit, one should split the proof into 2 separate parts. One part is the 'if  part' and the other is ... . Assuming that requiring to prove "if the circle of diameter CD is tangent to the line AB, then .... ", QN is automatically the radius of the circle CND.